# How can I use multiple versions of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I have a page that requires several versions of jQuery: `jquery-1.11.0.min.js`, `jquery-1.10.2.js`, and `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js`.

I want to use **tabs**, which requires `jquery-1.10.2.js` and `jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js`.
But I also want to do [**this image slider**](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html), which requires `jquery-1.11.0.min.js`

The tabs works perfectly without the js for the image slider, and vice versa.

How can I use both???

I tried the following for each one, but that didn't help any.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you don't need multiple versions of jquery. if the plugin supports 1.10.2, it also supports 1.11.0 because nothing was removed between those two versions.

Comment: Have you tried just using `jquery-1.11.0.min.js`?

Answer (score 0):

You can' just download the latest jQuery UI for tabs which always supports the latest jquery.

As soon as you load a newer version, it will override the old one.